# Angular ng-model and input field value

Tags: angularjs, input

I want to retrieve the value of the input field as the user is typing.

I don't really get what I'm doing with ng-model in this circumstance.

router:

```
            .state('layout.manifest', {
                url: '/manifest',
                templateUrl: 'Content/js/apps/store/views/manifest.html',
                controller: 'manifestController',
                controllerAs: 'manifestVm',
                data: { pageTitle: 'Manifest' }
            })
```

html:

```
    <input 
        type="text"
        ng-model="scanCode" 
        ng-keypress="manifestVm.scanId()"  
    />
```

controller:

```
vm.scanId = function () {
    console.log(vm.scanCode);
}
```

This returns **undefined**.

I've tried other methods for retrieving the value directly but to no avail.

[ EDIT: updated to include router/controller for clarity ]

Comment: In your controller define $scope.inputs = { scanCode: "" }

Then you can access it in the template with inputs.scanCode.

And in the controller you can access with $scope.inputs.scanCode

Answer (score 0):

As simple as below:

**View:**

```
<input ng-model="vm.model" ng-change="vm.see(vm.model)" >
```

**Controller:**

```
vm.see = function (model){
  console.log(model);
};
```

Comment: try `controller: "manifestController as vm"` in your routes ?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
<input 
    type="text"
    ng-model="manifestVm.scanCode" 
    ng-keypress="manifestVm.scanId()"  
/>
```

Comment: Shoot, I got the controller as backwards. I've fixed my post. But your code still doesn't work - it'll be identical to mine.

Comment: It should be **ControllerName** as *alias*. So it should be correct. Can you please include your controller as well as your entire HTML.

Comment: I see it. model needs vm reference.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up. Opening post fixed.

Comment: Can you also post your controller? Now I see you put your controllerAs manifestVm. I need to see your controller since in your controller you're using the vm object so I need to see what that is referencing.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've implemented it:

```
<input 
    type="text" 
    id="scanInput" 
    ng-model="manifestVm.scannedCode" 
    ng-change="manifestVm.findPackageById()" />



    vm.scannedCode=null;
    vm.findPackageById = function () {
        var inputValue = event.target.value;
    }
```

I've got the value, though the model has nothing to do with it.